# "Connected by" vs "Connected with" vs "Connected to"

Tags: word-choice, differences, word-usage

I want to know the difference and when to use which construction.
For instance:

> The island and the city are connected with a bridge

or

> The island and the city are connected by a bridge

?

---

> The TV is connected to the computer

or

> The TV is connected with the computer

?

---

> Somebody is connected to someone

or

> Somebody is connected with someone

? (Meaning emotional feelings.)

Comment: The difference is the same as that imparted by the respective prepositions which lend distinct meanings. I think this is GR as it applies to any set of propositions in similar sentence structures.

Comment: *The island and the city are connected **with** a bridge* has focus on the island and the city. Moreover, the prep. *with* does not adequately show that the connection is **between** the island and the city, just that they are both connected "with" the bridge (i.e., Not necessarily with each other, a question of mere argument in this case.). OTOH, *The island and the city are connected **by** a bridge* may have the focus on the bridge instead. In this case, clearly, the connection is established between the island and the mainland, the bridge serving as the means/agency of connection.

Comment: Both "the island is connected to the city by a bridge" and "the island is connected with the city by a bridge" sound OK to me.  Other choices of prepositions in that sentence sound awkward or wrong.

Answer (score 0):

**The difference between 'Connected by' and 'Connected to'**

First I will explain the meaning of the examples:

The island and the city are connected **with** a bridge

- Means that the physical method that has been employed to connect the two things, is a bridge.

or

The island and the city are connected **by** a bridge

- Means that there is a bridge available that allows one to get between the island and the City

The TV is connected **to** the computer

- Means that some kind of physical connection exists between the TV and the computer

The TV is connected **with** the computer

- Means that's there's a connection, an ongoing extant relationship between the TV and the computer that allows them to work together

Somebody is connected **to** someone

- Means that someone has any kind of link to someone else. Knows them, is related, is in the same kind of business, has the same name, is tied to them by a rope...

Somebody is connected **with** someone

- Means that some kind of connection or relationship of any kind is happening (can be emotional or not)

**To summarise:**

'**to**' is talking about the existence of some kind of link

'**by**' is talking about the link going on or the relationship it enables.

By:
https://www.englishclub.com/efl/articles/vocabulary/8-ways-to-use-the-preposition-by/

To:
https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/to